# nginx configuration for angular application- sub-domain mapping now working

Tags: angular, nginx, nginx-config

i have an angular application. i deployed in server using. it works with following name http://localserver:9090

but i need to make it work when it has sub-domain: http://localserver:9090/finance

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /var/www/html;

server_name _;


server_tokens off;
proxy_cache off;
resolver 127.0.0.1 valid=10s;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
}
```

can anyone help me how to render home when user hits: http://localserver:9090/finance

Answer (score 0):

build your angular application with `--baseHref="/finance"` option, then all paths will be prepended with baseHref

Comment: no it is not working: asset is looking in location http://localserver:9090/runtime.26209474bfa8dc87a77c.js instead of  http://localserver:9090/finance/runtime.26209474bfa8dc87a77c.js

Comment: yet, without falling back to 'index.html' your application will not be opened when you hit /finance/inapp/path. it is still required to make angular routing catch up and work properly

Comment: @ndrei, thanks for your response. using above solution it works but i need to do it using nginx configuation instead of changing index.html

Comment: it is possible with some hacks. for example you can add rewrites to add '/finance' for every requested resource, but how would you know then which exact app had made a request for resource when you have several ones hosted on several subdomains? Valid options is building with --baseHref (or you can modify  angular.json to make angular build command follow that option)

Answer (score 0):

following change in the nginx configuartion is solved the problem.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
}
```

thanks